# How to monitor all lync users instant message via C# console application?

Tags: ucma

I have created UCMA trusted application using C# console application.

I want to monitor all Lync Users instant messaging calls (in one place)  as well as store their conversations in the database via this console application.

Is it possible?.

If possible, please give an idea or any url.

Comment: Why use a console application? Wouldn't a headless daemon/Windows-Service process be more appropriate? And FWIW, Lync can archive all conversations by itself anyway.

Answer (score 0):

UCMA trusted applications will only respond to traffic to the endpoints associated with that application so if you want to monitor all instant message traffic it would be the wrong API.

I would suggest using SIP Application API [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh364644(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh364644%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to create a server application.  This will also require the use of MSPL documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh364805%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

As Dai has asked - is the console application a requirement or will a windows service be ok?

Answer (score 0):

Try our this sample application [SipSnoop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Lync-Server-2013-Log-and-6cbaa872) it basically shows all the metadata passing throught the lync server, you can tweak around it according to your requirement.