# How to monitor my Lync by C# console application (using trusted application endpoint)?

Tags: ucma

I have created console application with Trusted Application (UCMA) endpoint using C# Which is running in separate server (Computer).

I have installed Lync in my laptop. My requirement is to:

The console application should show subject, sip uri and date time of each instant message calls received by the Lync.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [How to monitor all lync users instant message via C# console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604524/how-to-monitor-all-lync-users-instant-message-via-c-sharp-console-application/24625947#24625947)

Answer in full there but in summary a UCMA app would be only able to track calls to it and not all calls on the network.  Look to the SIP Application API and MSPL based solution.