# How can i monitor the lync client for focus

Tags: c#, lync

I'm in the progress of making a little code that activates some lights triggered by some events from the Lync client.
I monitor Changes in presence and i have found a way to see new incoming messages.

What i would like to do is stop the blinking when the lync chat is in focus and I'm actively engaged in a conversation.

What I'm looking for is basically the flashing event down at the taskbar or the "pling" when a message is incoming and you are focused on an other application.

Is there such an event that can be monitored with the Lync SDK?

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604524/how-to-monitor-all-lync-users-instant-message-via-c-sharp-console-application/24625947#24625947) if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the correction of my bad spelling.

Comment: Thanks for the correction of my bad spelling.
The tip did not help. I'm not looking for a server side solution, rather a client side solution like http://bridgeoc.blogspot.se/2014/11/popup-notification-of-new-lync-message.html but i don't know how to stop the action when it got my attention.